# Is there a way to Find out which PHP script has updated the MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli

I can find out that certain query has been fired to MySQL database from the mysqlBinLog. But is there a way to find which PHP file has executed those queries ?

My problem is- I am not able to trace which php file in the Application is firing a particular update query.

I have searched in the whole application for that particular update query but I didn't find any match. It is generated programatically somewhere and get executed.

Since the code footprint is too big, it is practically not possible for me to go and put a log statement everywhere.

Comment: Have you tried searching for the query in the source code?

Comment: Is there any cron job running in your server?

Comment: yes. i tried searching in the source code and didn't found any. There are several crons running and I scanned through them as well. But didn't get a clue.

Comment: Could you not simply rename the table it's referencing (temporarily) so that it fires an error? Then you are likely to find the source?

Comment: Mysql offers an enterprise tool that can work together with the PHP mysql client that even tells you the file and the line of code where the query was executed. The interfaces are open source even, so you could run your own as well ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap a logger class around the database access library (PDO) and log the query together with a backtrace.

```
class LoggerPDO extends PDO
{
    function query()
    {
        return $this->logger('query', func_get_args());
    }

    private function logger($method, $args)
    {
        // log query
        debug_print_backtrace();
        // push to parent
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, 'parent::' . $method), $args);
    }
}
```

You can add other methods that need logging too, such as `prepare()` or `execute()`.

If you're using `mysql_` functions, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

U can put logs from where update queries are fired and get these logs info